# How to add Meta Title and Meta Description in WooCommerce category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using All in one SEO Pack plugin for Meta Title & Meta Description for my website. My website having WooCommerce and All in one SEO pack does not support Meta Title & Meta Description for WooCommerce categories page.

So I have used below code to create custom fields for Meta Title & Meta Description for WooCommerce categories in admin area.

```
function wh_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
    ?>

    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="wh_meta_title"><?php _e('Meta Title', 'wh'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="wh_meta_title" id="wh_meta_title">
        <p class="description"><?php _e('Enter a meta title, <= 60 character', 'wh'); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="wh_meta_desc"><?php _e('Meta Description', 'wh'); ?></label>
        <textarea name="wh_meta_desc" id="wh_meta_desc"></textarea>
        <p class="description"><?php _e('Enter a meta description, <= 160 character', 'wh'); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

//Product Cat Edit page
function wh_taxonomy_edit_meta_field($term) {

    //getting term ID
    $term_id = $term->term_id;

    // retrieve the existing value(s) for this meta field.
    $wh_meta_title = get_term_meta($term_id, 'wh_meta_title', true);
    $wh_meta_desc = get_term_meta($term_id, 'wh_meta_desc', true);
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="wh_meta_title"><?php _e('Meta Title', 'wh'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="wh_meta_title" id="wh_meta_title" value="<?php echo esc_attr($wh_meta_title) ? esc_attr($wh_meta_title) : ''; ?>">
            <p class="description"><?php _e('Enter a meta title, <= 60 character', 'wh'); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="wh_meta_desc"><?php _e('Meta Description', 'wh'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <textarea name="wh_meta_desc" id="wh_meta_desc"><?php echo esc_attr($wh_meta_desc) ? esc_attr($wh_meta_desc) : ''; ?></textarea>
            <p class="description"><?php _e('Enter a meta description', 'wh'); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

add_action('product_cat_add_form_fields', 'wh_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 1);
add_action('product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'wh_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 1);

// Save extra taxonomy fields callback function.
function wh_save_taxonomy_custom_meta($term_id) {

    $wh_meta_title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'wh_meta_title');
    $wh_meta_desc = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'wh_meta_desc');

    update_term_meta($term_id, 'wh_meta_title', $wh_meta_title);
    update_term_meta($term_id, 'wh_meta_desc', $wh_meta_desc);
}

add_action('edited_product_cat', 'wh_save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 1);
add_action('create_product_cat', 'wh_save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 1);
```

Above code works perfectly in admin area. But how to display entered Meta Title & Meta Description on front end on category pages?

What hooks I should add in `functions.php` file so that it gets displayed in category pages in frontend?

Comment: are you using any seo plugin ?

Comment: Yes all in one seo pack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As you are using All in One SEO, so none of the wp default hook/filter
> will work as this plugin modify all the title, so you have to use
> [**`aioseop_title`**](http://hookr.io/filters/aioseop_title/), filter for Meta Title. and for Meta
> description you have to use [**`wp_head`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head).

**For Meta Title**

```
add_filter('aioseop_title', 'wh_alter_pro_cat_title', 1);

function wh_alter_pro_cat_title($title)
{
    global $paged;
    if (is_product_category())
    {
        $page = get_query_var('page');
        if ($paged > $page)
        {
            $page = $paged;
        }

        $term = get_queried_object();
        $title = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'wh_meta_title', true);
        $title = !empty($title) ? $title : $term->name;
        $page_part = (!empty($page) && ($page > 1)) ? ' | ' . 'Page ' . $page : '';
        $title .= ' | ' . get_bloginfo('name') . $page_part;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

**For Meta Description**

```
add_action('wp_head', 'wh_alter_pro_cat_desc', 5);

function wh_alter_pro_cat_desc()
{
    if (is_product_category())
    {
        $term = get_queried_object();
        $productCatMetaDesc = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'wh_meta_desc', true);
        if (empty($productCatMetaDesc))
            return;

        ?>
        <meta name="description" content="<?= $productCatMetaDesc; ?>">
        <?php
    }
}
```

*All the code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Codes is tested and works.**

Helpful link [Adding custom field to product category in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40183439/5019802)

Comment: I faced the same issue a long time back when I was developing a Woo Store for one of my client, and I did't get any helpful solution so I wrote that tutorial and answer. and glad that it help you. don't forget to upvote and accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Display details on product category archive pages
add_action(
    'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 
    'wpm_product_cat_archive_add_meta'
);

function wpm_product_cat_archive_add_meta() {
    $t_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
    $term_meta_content = $term_meta['custom_term_meta'];
    if ( $term_meta_content != '' ) {
        echo '<div class="woo-sc-box normal rounded full">';
            echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $term_meta_content );
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can display custom meta title and meta description on frontend by using the following hook.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop','display_custom_meta_info');
    function display_custom_meta_info(){
       global $wp_query;
       $cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
       $title_meta = get_term_meta($cat_obj->term_id
    ,'wh_meta_title',true);
       $desc_meta = get_term_meta($cat_obj->term_id
    ,'wh_meta_desc',true);

      $woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description = $title_meta.$desc_meta;

return $woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description;

    }
```

You can always use other hooks to modify the display of metas by following the [template structure](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/)

Comment: check this code inside , archive-product.php

global $wp_query;
       $cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
       $title_meta = get_post_meta($cat_obj->term_id;
    ,'wh_meta_title',true);
       $desc_meta = get_post_meta($cat_obj->term_id;
    ,'wh_meta_desc',true);

echo the $title_meta and $desc_meta

Comment: Oh I realized that I placed ; in catid , can you check the code now

global $wp_query;
       $cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
       $title_meta = get_post_meta($cat_obj->term_id
    ,'wh_meta_title',true);
       $desc_meta = get_post_meta($cat_obj->term_id
    ,'wh_meta_desc',true);

Also try to place static category ID in place of $cat_obj->term_id and check that if it issues.

Comment: i have already removed ; before placing above code, still it was not working

Comment: Again corrected ,

global $wp_query; $cat_obj = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); $title_meta = get_term_meta($cat_obj->term_id ,'wh_meta_title',true); $desc_meta = get_term_meta($cat_obj->term_id ,'wh_meta_desc',true);

This should work

Comment: still no luck, i have placed above code in wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php at top, is it correct place?

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try this code its working file.**
**For Meta Title**

```
add_filter('aioseo_title', 'wh_alter_pro_cat_title', 1);

function wh_alter_pro_cat_title($title)
{
    global $paged;
    if (is_product_category())
    {
        $page = get_query_var('page');
        if ($paged > $page)
        {
            $page = $paged;
        }

        $term = get_queried_object();
        $title = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'wh_meta_title', true);
        $title = !empty($title) ? $title : $term->name;
        $page_part = (!empty($page) && ($page > 1)) ? ' | ' . 'Page ' . $page : '';
        $title .= ' | ' . get_bloginfo('name') . $page_part;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

**For Meta Description**

```
add_action('wp_head', 'wh_alter_pro_cat_desc', 5);

function wh_alter_pro_cat_desc()
{
    if (is_product_category())
    {
        $term = get_queried_object();
        $productCatMetaDesc = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'wh_meta_desc', true);
        if (empty($productCatMetaDesc))
            return;

        ?>
        <meta name="description" content="<?= $productCatMetaDesc; ?>">
        <?php
    }
}
```