# Adding custom display_type to WooCommerce categories (product_cat taxonomy)

Tags: woocommerce

Under a category, WooCommerce ships with a field called 'display_type'. It has 4 values:

- Default
- Products
- Subcategories
- Both

How do I add more options in there?

I found the function in the source code: [add_category_fields](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/23710744c01ded649d6a94a4eaea8745e543159f/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-taxonomies.php#L116) and it doesn't look like that there is a hook, where additional fields can be added.

---

Had I been lazy, then I would probably just have added a new meta-field with my customly added options (using [ACF](https://advancedcustomfields.com)).

---

**Bonus question:** For some reason, then I can't get the value of the `display_type`-field, unless using `$wpdb`. `$display_type = get_term_meta( $term->ID, 'display_type' );` Doesn't seem to work. I elaborated on this question [over here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/385519/how-to-get-all-term-meta-for-a-taxonomy-getting-term-meta-for-taxonomy).

Comment: See: [Adding custom field to product category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23469841/adding-custom-field-to-product-category/40183439#40183439) …Try to use `$term->term_id` instead of  `$term->ID`